# Is mbed RTOS suitable for commercial motion control solutions

Tags: embedded, mbed, motion

Is the mbed RTOS suitable for commercial motion control applications? Is it advisable to separate the actual motion controller from the network handler, etc (i.e. motion controller in separate MCU)?

Does anyone know of any commercial motion controllers which operate on the mbed's RTOS?

Comment: Since mbed-ARM's docs say that it is just a C++ wrapper over Keil's RTX, and since that implies you will have to become a customer of Keil, why don't you write Keil and find out? They want your money and I think they will help you figure out if mbed+RTX is a good fit for you.

Comment: @jonk - Both Mbed OS and Keil RTX are open source and royalty free.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Mbed OS uses [CMSIS-RTOS2](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5), which is built on top of Keil RTX 5. This is totally capable of doing hard realtime.

Regarding network handling, it depends on your requirements. If you need full, 100% timing guarantees then a network handler which might trigger an interrupt will cause problems, and splitting it up could be good. This would be something best measured first.

Comment: do you work for ARM?